# MySQL SUM If More Than & Less Than

Tags: mysql, sum

I need to sum from **price** column if they are have more than value 200.

Otherwise, I need to sum if they are have less than value 200.

The result I want to grouping them by Date.

Please see the **orders** table:

```
price       date_transaction
537         2014-03-28 11:44:40
123         2014-03-28 14:35:21
96          2014-03-28 15:43:17
341         2014-03-28 16:12:42
309         2014-03-29 15:47:48
223         2014-03-29 19:22:28
115         2014-03-29 23:31:34
109         2014-03-29 23:44:16
```

I want to result like this below:

```
date_transaction    sum_of_two_hundred_or_more      sum_of_less_than_200
2014-03-28          878                             219
2014-03-29          532                             224
2014-03-30          0                               0
2014-03-31          0                               0
```

And here is what I've tried, but it only show the more than 200 only.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT DATE(date_transaction) AS date_transaction,
SUM(price) AS sum_of_two_hundred_or_more
FROM orders
WHERE price > 200
AND date_transaction BETWEEN '2014-03-26' AND '2014-03-31' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(date_transaction)
ORDER BY DATE(date_transaction) ASC;
```

Comment: does my answer solved your question?

Comment: Yes Worked Successfully. Thank you!

Comment: great. you're welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DATE(date_transaction) AS date_transaction,
    SUM (CASE WHEN price >= 200 THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS sum_of_two_hundred_or_more
    SUM (CASE WHEN price < 200 THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS sum_of_two_hundred_less
FROM orders
WHERE date_transaction BETWEEN '2014-03-26' AND '2014-03-31' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(date_transaction)
ORDER BY DATE(date_transaction) ASC
```